# Local Gradient Pattern Implementation

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, feature-extraction, lbph-algorithm

I am trying to understand **Local Gradient Pattern** which is described in [Local gradient pattern - A novel feature representation for facial
expression recognition](http://jad.shahroodut.ac.ir/article_147_65fecf9ec71ccfdba7f9ba1bf07251b1.pdf).

There is an example of calculating new value of a pixel like below:

[image: pattern calculation]

I see that the center pixel's (which is 25) `Pattern-1` value is `10` and `Pattern-2` value is `01`. I have several questions.

- What will be the new value of that center pixel?
- How LGP is related with LBP?
- Is there any pseudo code for converting a 2D matrix using LGP (Python preferred)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What will be the new value of that center pixel?

It depends on the **encoding** scheme. The reference paper does not clearly explain how local gradient patterns are encoded. One possible encoding would be:

[image: LGP]

where

[image: f(x)]

If you introduce the intensity values of your example into the expressions above the pattern code results:

[image: code calculation example]

Please notice that the effect of using a different encoding would be a reordering of the histogram bins, but this would not have an impact on the classification accuracy.

> How LGP is related with LBP?

LGP is simply one of the many **LBP variants**. Take a look at [this book](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642392887) for a comprehensive review.

> Is there any pseudo code for converting a 2D matrix using LGP (Python preferred)?

Give this code a try:

```
import numpy as np

def LGP_codes(img, r=1):
    padded = np.pad(img, (r, r), 'constant')
    a1 = padded[:-2*r, :-2*r]
    b1 = padded[:-2*r, r:-r]
    a2 = padded[:-2*r, 2*r:]
    b2 = padded[r:-r, 2*r:]
    a3 = padded[2*r:, 2*r:]
    b3 = padded[2*r:, r:-r]
    a4 = padded[2*r:, :-2*r]
    b4 = padded[r:-r, :-2*r]
    codes = (a1 >= a3) + 2*(a2 >= a4) + 4*(b1 >= b3) + 8*(b2 >= b4)
    return codes[r:-r, r:-r]
```

**Demo**

```
In [31]: patch = np.array([[18, 25, 14], 
    ...:                   [85, 25, 86], 
    ...:                   [45, 65, 14]])
    ...: 

In [32]: LGP_codes(patch)
Out[32]: array([[9]])
```

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation. Really appreciate it. Can you check this? https://gist.github.com/arsho/251ff14df1c0ed88c469bad17c767efe

Comment: If you have to process many images or the images are large, I would recommend utilizing vectorized rather than scalar code since explicit for loops are likely to slow down program execution.

Comment: I do not need to process many images. This is for demonstration of the above algorithm. Have you checked the code? I would be glad if you make a review.

Comment: Yes, I checked the code, that's why I suggested that you use vectorized code (as in my SO answer) rather than scalar code (as in your git repository).